# Multiple DHCP networks on Raspbian Stretch

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi3, stretch

I am trying to make my Raspberry work on multiple wifi networks. Quite a lot of examples can be found but most of them are focussed on 2 files, the /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf and the /etc/network/interfaces. 
Since I am using stretch these instruction don’t work for /etc/network/interfaces.

This is what I want to do.. I want to be able to connect to 2 different wifi works (one at home and one at work).. both are dhcp.. 
I change the wpa_supplicant file and this is how it looks;

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=NL

network={
        ssid="Homenetwork"
        psk="Password"
        id_str="home"
}

network={
        ssid="Officenetwork"
        psk=NONE
        id_str="work"
}
```

I didnt make any changes to /etc/dhcpcd.conf since I just want to use dhcp. The problem starts when I added the office network.. it no longer connects to the wifi. While just only using my home one in /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf works fine.
Any ideas what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue, where everything worked fine using one network, but stopped when I added a second one to `wpa_supplicant`.
I found my error by looking at `/var/log/syslog`

Turned out that I had my encrypted `wpa_passphrase` between parentheses `""` and this stopped `wpa_supplicant` from doing its magic.

The `psk=NONE` in your second network therefore seems suspicious.

I didn't change a thing to `etc/network/interfaces` nor to `dhcpcd.conf`.
My `wpa_supplicant` file also contains the `priority` property, no idea if this has an influence.

Good luck!